# imported rhino .obj shows 0 faces 0 verts 0 tris

Tags: error

I'm exporting a model form rhino as an .obj importing it into blender, which then gives me no viewable model but is named in the scene collection?

is it something im doing wrong in rhino???

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've disabled the viewport visibility of your imported object, or it has been imported in a disabled state.

In the outliner, enable the "Viewport visibility" column/filter (*Funnel icon > Monitor icon*), then enable the Viewport visibility for your object.

[image]

Comment: Viewport visibility is on, but still nothing :( By imported in a disabled state do you mean the model itself in rhino isn't exported correctly?

Comment: I have no idea about Rhino's objs honestly: I just noticed that your entry "1234" was greyed out in the outliner.

Comment: If you upload your blender file (after import) I can check whether there is some info in it. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: ive added the download to the body of the question, thanks!!

Comment: Ok, unfortunately I don't see any data in the `1234` mesh. However, the file you've uploaded is not the same as in your screenshot (where the object was grayed out). At this point I really suspect that there's something wrong/not supported in your obj.